# mysql - how to combine two rows together if they have the same values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a form in which I add some details. Now, let's say I submit the form with the following details:

```
id_s: 3
id_m: 1
quantity: 5
```

It's all good, the information is stored in the table on a row. (see below)
[image: proof1]

Next, if I submit the form with the following:

```
id_s: 3
id_m: 1
quantity: 3
```

the table will contain two rows with same values instead of one merged with the information (see below)
[image: proof2]

What condition should I put in order to merge them into one row so it's gonna be the total of quantity?

Comment: Are `id_substatie`, `id_medicament` together the primary or unique key of this table?

Comment: no, they are not unique or primary, because they should not be

Comment: @Cristian25 Everything in your question says the combination of `id_substatie, id_medicament` *is* the primary key and so should be unique. If you want rows to be merged, when should they be allowed to not be merged?

Comment: my bad.. I just realised what I said. yes, they are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first two columns are unique, which is what I would expect from your description, then you can do this:

```
mysql> create table mytable  ( id_substatie int, id_medicament int, cantitate int );

mysql> alter table mytable add primary key (id_substatie, id_medicament);

mysql> insert into mytable values (3,1,5);

mysql> insert into mytable values (3,1,3) 
       on duplicate key update cantitate=cantitate+values(cantitate);

mysql> select * from mytable;
+--------------+---------------+-----------+
| id_substatie | id_medicament | cantitate |
+--------------+---------------+-----------+
|            3 |             1 |         8 |
+--------------+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The expression `cantitate+values(cantitate)` means the old value of that column plus the new value you tried to insert.

Comment: It seems to not work on my query. Can you check what's wrong? I tried figuring it out on my own but didn't seem to get the idea. Although I understood your solution and it seems logic

```INSERT INTO `substatie_stoc`(`id_substatie`, `id_medicament`, `cantitate`) VALUES ('". $_POST['substatii'] ."','". $medid ."','". $med_quantity ."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cantitate = cantitate + VALUES(cantitate)```

Comment: Can you please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE substatie_stoc` and edit your question above to include the result? I suspect you don't really have a unique constraint on the columns you need, and you do need that for `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to detect that the rows exists.

Comment: Or, more conventionally, make `(id_substatie, id_medicament)` the primary key.

Comment: Yes, I didn't have them as unique in the structure. Thank you so much good fellas!

Answer (score 0):

You could basically use a trigger for this before  every insert

```
   Create trigger t_sample on
   sample before insert
   For each row
   Begin
   Update sample s set 
   s.quantity=:OLD.quantity+:NEW.quantity 
   where s.id_s=:NEW.id_s and s.id_m=:NEW.id_m
    and s.quantity <>:NEW.quantity 
   ;
   End;
   /
```